# Plotting f(x) = sin x and f(x) = cos x on pgf/tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I'm new to graphing on TikZ/`pgf` and have been trying to figure this out but can't seem to find any helpful info for what I want. I want to plot the above functions over one period, i.e. on the interval `[0,2\pi]` and would like the tick marks on the graph to show the values `0, pi/2 , pi, 3pi/2, and 2pi`. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! Please help us help you by editing in a minimal working example of what you have tried. The problem seems relatively straight-forward with a little experience so I suspect there are particular areas we may need to focus on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Draw cosine and sine function with periods 1?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211662/draw-cosine-and-sine-function-with-periods-1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `pgfplots`

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
     clip=false,
     xmin=0,xmax=2*pi,
     %axis lines=left,
     %axis x line=middle,
     %axis y line=left,
     xtick={0,1.57,3.14,4.71,6.28},
     xticklabels={$0$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$,$\frac{3}{2}\pi$,$2\pi$}
     ]
      \addplot[domain=0:2*pi,samples=200,red]{sin(deg(x))}node[right,pos=0.9]{$f(x)=\sin x$};
      \addplot[domain=0:2*pi,samples=200,blue]{cos(deg(x))}node[right,pos=0.9]{$f(x)=\cos x$};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another variant will be:

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
     clip=false,
     xmin=0,xmax=2.5*pi,
     xlabel= $x$,
     ylabel=$f(x)$,
     ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,
     axis lines=middle,
     %axis x line=middle,
     %axis y line=left,
%     axis x line=middle,
     xtick={0,1.57,3.14,4.71,6.28},
     xticklabels={$0$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi\,$,$\,\,\,\frac{3}{2}\pi$,$\,\,\,2\pi$},
     %xticklabel style={anchor=north west}
     ]
      \addplot[domain=0:2*pi,samples=200,red]{sin(deg(x))}
                                node[right,pos=0.9,font=\footnotesize]{$f(x)=\sin x$};
      \addplot[domain=0:2*pi,samples=200,blue]{cos(deg(x))}
                                node[right,pos=1,font=\footnotesize]{$f(x)=\cos x$};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. The labels "f(x)=cos(x)" and "f(x)=sin(x)" would look better in smaller font, sitting beside the right endpoints of their graphs.

Comment: Change `node[right,pos=0.9]{$f(x)=\sin x$};` to `node[right]{$\scriptstyle f(x)=\sin x$};`