# sin wave with changing frequency

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to recreate this image of the EM spectrum:

[Electromagnetic Spectrum](https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-8d60e7a56b274a430e35bfbbb9aa650d-c)

I would like to draw a sin/cos wave of changing frequency as in the picture.

So far I've been doing something extremely hacky but this less than ideal because I can't change the form of the wave without manually going through and changing all the numbers. Can anyone suggest a more elegant solution that perhaps uses a single sine/cosine function?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (12,0);
\draw (0.2,1)node[left,font=\tiny] {$y=1$} -- (11.8,1);
\draw (0.2,-1)node[left,font=\tiny] {$y=-1$} -- (11.8,-1); 
\foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,12}{
\draw (\x,-0.2)node [below,font=\tiny,] {\x} -- (\x,0.2) ;
}
\draw[ultra thick, red] (0,0) sin (1,1);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (1,1) cos (2.0,0);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (2.0,0) sin (3,-1);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (3,-1) cos (3.9,0);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (3.9,0)  sin (4.8,1);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (4.8,1) cos (5.6,0);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (5.6,0) sin (6.4,-1);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (6.4,-1) cos (7.2,0);    

 \draw[ultra thick, red] (7.2,0)  sin (7.9,1);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (7.9,1) cos (8.55,0);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (8.55,0) sin (9.2,-1);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (9.2,-1) cos (9.7,0.0);

     \draw[ultra thick, red] (9.7,0)  sin (10.2,1);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (10.2,1) cos (10.6,0);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (10.6,0) sin (11.0,-1);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (11.0,-1) cos (11.3,0); %% the real business in this line 

         \draw[ultra thick, red] (11.3,0)  sin (11.6,1);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (11.6,1) cos (11.8,0);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (11.8,0) sin (12.0,-1);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (12.0,-1) cos (12.2,0); %% the real business in this line 

             \draw[ultra thick, red] (12.2,0)  sin (12.4,1);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (12.4,1) cos (12.55,0);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (12.55,0) sin (12.7,-1);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (12.7,-1) cos (12.85,0); %% the real business in this line 

                 \draw[ultra thick, red] (12.85,0)  sin (13.0,1);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (13.0,1) cos (13.1,0);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (13.1,0) sin (13.2,-1);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (13.2,-1) cos (13.3,0); %% the real business in this line 

 \draw[ultra thick, red] (13.3,0)  sin (13.4,1);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (13.4,1) cos (13.48,0);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (13.48,0) sin (13.56,-1);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (13.56,-1) cos (13.62,0); %% the real business in this line 

     \draw[ultra thick, red] (13.62,0)  sin (13.69,1);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (13.69,1) cos (13.76,0);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (13.76,0) sin (13.82,-1);    %% the real business in this line
\draw[ultra thick, red] (13.82,-1) cos (13.88,0); %% the real business in this line 
\draw[ultra thick, red] (13.88,0)  sin (13.92,1);    %% the real business in this line
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Current attempt]

Comment: You could use pgfplots and y=sin((a*x+b)*x)

Comment: There is actually no need to define all the points of your plot, as you did. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231052/plotting-fx-sin-x-and-fx-cos-x-on-pgf-tikz

Answer (score 8):

With blueshift.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[hide axis,red,width=16cm,height=4cm,thick] 
\addplot[domain=20:300,samples=800,        
colormap={}{ % Define the colormap from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243689/create-a-plot-line-with-a-gradient
            color(2cm)=(red);
            color(16cm)=(blue);
        },
        ultra thick, point meta=x*x,mesh]{sin(pow(x,2)/15)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: marmot...this is what I'm looking for...

Comment: marmot, how can I obtain inverted frequency?
I mean:
- before major frequency
- the low frequency

Comment: @RenatoP Try `\addplot[domain=20:300,samples=800,        
colormap={}{ color(2cm)=(red);
            color(16cm)=(blue);
        },
        ultra thick, point meta=x*x,mesh]{sin(150*pow(x,1/2))};`. You could also ask a new question. Or you could just flip the picture. `\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1]
\begin{axis}[hide axis,red,width=16cm,height=4cm,thick] 
\addplot[domain=20:300,samples=800,        
colormap={}{  color(2cm)=(red);
            color(16cm)=(blue);
        },
        ultra thick, point meta=x*x,mesh]{sin(pow(x,2)/15)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: yes, it works!

I have one error (unexpected \end {document} after \begin {axis} the first \begin {axis} is not closed, but the file is well compiled and is ok)

My last question is: is it possible to have more hight wave and amplitude as you procede?

Comment: @RenatoP Could you please ask a separate question? There is no charge. ;-) (I mean official question, not just comment.)

Answer (score 5):

A sine wave with increasing frequency has the expression `sin(deg((\fmin+\x*((\fmax-\fmin))/\xmax)*\x))` if the frequency increase is linear, and `sin(deg(exp(ln(\fmin)+\x/\xmax*(ln(\fmax)-ln(\fmin)))*\x))` if the frequency increase is exponential. I have seen that the exponential increase seems to provide better looking results. In the following code, set `\xmax` to the maximum value of `x`, `\fmin` to the minimum frequency, and `\fmax` to the maximum frequency. The commented line uses linear frequency increase, and the uncommented line uses exponential frequency increase.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\xmax}{14}
    \newcommand{\fmin}{(pi/3)}
    \newcommand{\fmax}{(2*pi)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:\xmax, samples=500]
\draw (0,0) -- (12,0);
\draw (0.2,1)node[left,font=\tiny] {$y=1$} -- (11.8,1);
\draw (0.2,-1)node[left,font=\tiny] {$y=-1$} -- (11.8,-1); 
\foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,12}{
    \draw (\x,-0.2)node [below,font=\tiny,] {\x} -- (\x,0.2) ;
}

% The following line uses linear frequency increase
%\draw[ultra thick, red] plot (\x, {sin(deg((\fmin+\x*((\fmax-\fmin))/\xmax)*\x))} );
% The following line uses exponential frequency increase
\draw[ultra thick, red] plot (\x, {sin(deg(exp(ln(\fmin)+\x/\xmax*(ln(\fmax)-ln(\fmin)))*\x))} );

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how can I invert the frequency: first greater frequency and after less frequency.Finaly I should have first short wave, after hight wave. I do not know "the function.
Renato

Comment: javi_gg1 I'munable to made the invertion  (before more frequency after less)

Answer (score 3):

A PSTricks solution only for comparison purposes.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-calculate}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](0,-1.5)(\pscalculate{2*pi},1.5)
    \psplot[plotpoints=3000]{0}{2 Pi mul}{sin(x^3/2)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Flipped version

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-calculate}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](0,-1.5)(\pscalculate{2*pi},1.5)
    \psplot[plotpoints=3000]{0}{2 Pi mul}{sin((x-TwoPi)^3/2)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how can I invert the frequency: first greater frequency and after less frequency.Finaly I should have first short wave, after hight wave. I do not know "the function.

Comment: cannot compile,
thi is th error:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Package xkeyval Error: `potpoints' undefined in families `,pstricks,pst-tools,pst-node,pst-arrow,pst-3d,pstricks-add,pst-plot'.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
I' ve upload pst-calculate and pst-plot
Use pdflatex to compile

Comment: @RenatoP: Compile it with `xelatex` or `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`.