# how to obtain a loop of wave

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis,red,width=16cm,height=8cm,thick] 
        \addplot[domain=20:300,samples=800, colormap={}{ color(2cm)=(red); 
  },
  ultra thick, point meta=x*x,mesh]{sin(150*pow(x,1/2))};
 %You could also ask a new question. Or you could just flip the picture. 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1] 
        \begin{axis}[hide axis,red,width=16cm,height=4cm,thick]
            \addplot[domain=20:300,samples=800, colormap={}{ color(2cm)=(red); color(16cm)=(blue); },
            ultra thick, point meta=x*x,mesh]
                {sin(pow(x,2)/15)};
        \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code work well for me. But I would obtain just one more thing:
- How can I obtain a more hight wave the more waves are tracked?
I would increase also distance between waves

Comment: For those who are wondering: the code comes from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405054/121799) and the comments below. ;-)

Comment: Could you please try to reword a bit? You want to increase the amplitude, right? And the overall wave length? And what else?

Comment: yes that's right. but I would that this occur on the way that wave are tracked:
I mean: the first  wave will have amplitude and wave lenght = 1; 
the second =2
third = 3
and so on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code does not compile, unfortunately, since you have unmatched `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\begin{axis}` environments. Here is my answer as far as I understand the question. It is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405054/121799) and the parametrization of the last example is borrowed from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405058/121799). This shows how one may flip the direction and increase the amplitude. If you want to change the number of oscillations, you could change the domain.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{Changing the function}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[hide axis,red,width=16cm,height=6cm,thick] 
\addplot[domain=20:300,samples=800,        
colormap={}{ color(2cm)=(blue);
            color(16cm)=(red);
        },
        ultra thick, point meta=x*x,mesh]{sin(150*pow(x,1/2))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subsubsection*{Flipping the direction}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1]
\begin{axis}[hide axis,red,width=16cm,height=6cm,thick] 
\addplot[domain=20:300,samples=800,        
colormap={}{  color(2cm)=(red);
            color(16cm)=(blue);
        },
        ultra thick, point meta=x*x,mesh]{sin(pow(x,2)/15)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\subsubsection*{Modulating the amplitude}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1]
\begin{axis}[hide axis,red,width=16cm,height=6cm,thick] 
\addplot[domain=20:300,samples=800,        
colormap={}{  color(2cm)=(red);
            color(16cm)=(blue);
        },
        ultra thick, point meta=x*x,mesh]{sin(pow(x,2)/15)/(x/20)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\subsubsection*{Modulating the amplitude and the wave length}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1,declare function={% parametrization based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405058/121799
amplitude(\x)=pow(\x,-1/2)*sin(exp(ln(\fmin)+\x/\xmax*(ln(\fmax)-ln(\fmin)))*\x);}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmin}{20}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmax}{240}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\fmin}{(pi/3)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\fmax}{(2*pi)}
\begin{axis}[hide axis,red,width=16cm,height=6cm,thick] 
\addplot[domain=20:300,samples=800,        
colormap={}{  color(2cm)=(red);
            color(16cm)=(blue);
        },
        ultra thick, point meta=x*x,mesh]{amplitude(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: marmott, can you made modification on the original code ojf  javi_gg1?
I would obtain a fine tuning of the wave...

Comment: @RenatoP If you tell me what, you want, I will be happy to try. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464754/can-someone-explain-me-this-function) you asked another question. Do you want to have an exponentially growing wave?

Comment: Hi marmot,
thank you for your patience. The prob is 
1 - what I want
2 - how difficult is to explain in in English. I try:
I would have a frequency wave (like the one that Javi_gg1 show) but:
1 - inverted (before hight frequency, very hight frequency, then low frequency. The most similar is your III example)
2 - if possible with the same code of Javi (I mean not a functionalists, but a trigonometric function. I will tell you why)
3 - if possible, when the wavelength increases, it increases also the interval between them (but I think is natural that)

Is it possible?

Comment: @RenatoP I added something...

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @RenatoP There is now a fourth example in which the amplitude and the frequency change.

Comment: ok! Now I've seen what you wrote