# can someone explain me this function?

Tags: tikz-pgf

on my question, user Javi_gg1 send me an answer that's right for me.
This answer have  this code

```
\draw[ultra thick, red] plot (\x, {sin(deg(exp(ln(\fmin)+\x/\xmax*(ln(\fmax)-ln(\fmin)))*\x))} );
```

I could not understand how he works. is there anyone (maybe javi_gg1) who can explain it to me?
Because I would change some aspect.

Comment: Can you add a link to the answer you're talking about? But perhaps this is better left as a comment to the answer.

Comment: This is a parametric plot with `\x` denoting the parameter, the x-coordinate being equal to `\x` and y being `sin(deg(exp(ln(\fmin)+\x/\xmax*(ln(\fmax)-ln(\fmin)))*\x))`. Without a referral to the post, one cannot tell what the domain and are because they were either set outside the plot or the default values, nor what `\fmax` and `\fmin` are. The [answer you are referring to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405058/121799) sets `domain=0:\xmax` and `samples=500`.

Comment: I guess your question is more a math question. `exp(ln(\fmin)+\x/\xmax*(ln(\fmax)-ln(\fmin)))*\x` can be rewritten as `\fmin*((\fmax/\fmin)^(\x/\xmax))*\x`, so it multiplies `\x` by an exponential that equals `\fmin` at `\x=0` and `\fmax` at `\x=\xmax`. Why the author of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405058/121799) has chosen to write it in this way, is hard to say, but may not necessarily be a question that is suited for this forum. If you really want to know what this function does, plot it (without wrapping it into `sin(deg(...*\x))`.

Comment: @marmot ooh marmots are very good at mathematics! `:)`

Comment: the post is: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405048/sin-wave-with-changing-frequency/405058#405058