# trigonometry question:how to change frequency

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would change the formula that let this TiKZ function to draw frequency wave.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

    \newcommand{\xmax}{14}
    \newcommand{\fmin}{(pi/3)}
    \newcommand{\fmax}{(2*pi)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:\xmax, samples=500]

    \draw[ultra thick, red] plot (\x, {sin(deg(exp(ln(\fmin)+\x/\xmax*(ln(\fmax)-ln(\fmin)))*\x))} );

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I think I understand how it works.
But I still can't obtain the result I would.

I think, the draw function

```
\draw[ultra thick, red] plot (\x, {sin(deg(exp(ln(\fmin)+\x/\xmax*(ln(\fmax)-ln(\fmin)))*\x))} );
```

can draw the wave without a cycle (foreach or similar), because 
the `\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:\xmax, samples=500]` parameters (`domain= 0:\xmax`) tell to the `\begin{tikzpicture}` to repeat the `\draw` from o to `\xmax`

But, I'm  not able to change the `\draw` to obtain an image that start from hight frequency to low.

I don't understand the trigonometric funcion.

Can someone help me to modify this function to obtain that?

Comment: Please read [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192)

Comment: Do you have a sketch of what the result should look like?

Comment: no, I do not have sketch. But, I will prefer to obtain result with Latex. Can you give me link to sketch?

Comment: Sorry cavern I did't understand well you question before. You can see the image that I want, compiling the code before. But inverted. Hight frequency before, low frequency then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there is no text etc. simply use `xscale=-1` to invert left and right

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

    \newcommand{\xmax}{14}
    \newcommand{\fmin}{(pi/3)}
    \newcommand{\fmax}{(2*pi)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:\xmax, samples=500,xscale=-1]

    \draw[ultra thick, red] plot (\x, {sin(deg(exp(ln(\fmin)+\x/\xmax*(ln(\fmax)-ln(\fmin)))*\x))} );

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you can use the `axis` environment from `pgfplots`, you can also reverse the direction of the x axis:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      samples=1000,
      x dir=reverse,
      hide axis
    ]
      \addplot[domain=0:14] (x, {sin(deg(exp(ln((pi/3))+x/14*(ln((2*pi))-ln((pi/3))))*x))} );

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Needs pgfplots > 1.3)

Comment: nice answer, however this is `tikz` trick which draw mirror of defined function. correct solution is that op define new function with desired property. but this is not `tikz` problem ...

Comment: @Zarko Feel free to add the correct solution as an answer :)

Comment: no, defining function is task of op (it is math task, not latex), not mine nor yours :-)

Comment: oh, before i only write "nice answer" and forgot on +1. corrected now :-)

Comment: @RenatoP ??????

Comment: beautifull! 
last question:
is it possible to have this waves, from lower to hight?

Comment: @RenatoP Isn't this exactly what the code in your question does? From low to high frequency? [I guess now I'm totally confused about what you are trying to achieve...]

Comment: @RenatoP Some of the regular user of your chat room (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) speak Italian. If you think it would be easier for you explain your problem in Italian, maybe you could ask them to help translate it.

Comment: yes, it does this, but I would like that: the higher  frequency waves are "shorter" (or smaller) while, the lower frequency waves are talle (bigger).
have I confused you more?

Comment: thank you smarter, the first problem is the concept. For me is not simple to explain neither in italian nor in english

Comment: @RenatoP That sounds exactly like the 4th solution by our tikz wizard marmot https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464665/36296

Comment: yes, but the waves must have a high to low frequency.

Comment: @RenatoP Sorry, I'm totally confused now. Can you take pen and paper and draw the image exactly like you want it to be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87299/discussion-between-renatop-and-samcarter).